# Python search for image within image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I use `cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` to find small image in big image.

```
camera = dxcam.create()


class OverlayApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white')
        self.root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        window_width=1920
        window_height=1080
        self.root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+0+0')  
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=1920, height=1080, bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()

       
        self.squares = []
        
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_overlay)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update_overlay(self):
        while True:
            window_width = 1920
            window_height = 1080
            self.root.update()
            print("update")
            start = time.time()
            screenshot = camera.grab()
            img_rgb = np.array(screenshot)
            img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
       

            img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            template = cv2.imread("ai-2.jpg", 0)
            w, h = template.shape[::-1]
            
            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

            threshold = 0.9

            loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

            for square in self.squares:
                self.canvas.delete(square)

            for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):

                self.squares.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(pt[0], pt[1], pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h,outline='red'))

            self.root.update()

            fps=1/(time.time() - start)
            print(f"fps= {fps:.2f}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = OverlayApp()
    app.root.mainloop()
```

But one search takes up to 0.5 seconds. How can I improve my time without using AI to almost real time? If this is not possible, then how can I manually train the AI ​​on the datasets I created from `roboflow.com`?

I tried to use Hosted API way from `roboflow.com` but it takes 5s to one image. And i can`t use other way from this site because im on Windows 10

Comment: See cv2.matchTemplate() to search for a template (small image) inside a larger image. Note that it does not allow for scale or rotation differences and only searches for offsets in x and y.  Sorry I do not know dxcam

Comment: You don't need to reload your template every time through the loop - just load it once outside (before) the loop `template = cv2.imread("ai-2.jpg", 0)`

Comment: @fmw42 dxcam This is a library for capturing screens at up to 165hz, and I'm sure it definitely takes little time

Comment: @Mark Setchell thx